# Android M device admin activation fails

Tags: android, admin, device

My app uses device admin APIs and SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. In marshmallow device, when I try to activate or deactivate device admin of my app and if SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is not granted to my app then settings app of system crashes with cause that my app is not having SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. May I know the reason behind this? Does system revoke that permission temporarily?

Thanks.

Comment: Starting with android 6.0 only limited permissions are granted by default. You have to ask them at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but does device admin APIs require SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission?

Comment: SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is required to open a window over other applications just like Facebook messenger chat heads. Even without it you can work around just fine.

Comment: I require overlay permission for some other purpose. That's why I have declared it in manifest but if I revoke this permission from system settings, and try to activate or deactivate device admin of my app then settings app of system crashes.

Comment: you should post your error log. I can't say anything without it.

Comment: Security exception is thrown and settings app crashes and I won't be able to activate or deactivate device admin.